# Почему одинаковый хэш-код может быть у разных объектов?

Tags: java, hashcode

Хотел спросить:

И так же, как для equals(), для метода hashCode() есть официальные требования, прописанные в документации Oracle:

1. > Если два объекта равны
   >   (т.е. метод equals() возвращает true), у них должен быть одинаковый
   >   хэш-код.

Иначе наши методы будут лишены смысла. Проверка по hashCode(), как мы и сказали, должна идти первой для повышения быстродействия. Если хэш-коды будут разными, проверка вернет false, хотя объекты на самом деле равны (согласно нашему определению в методе equals()).

2. > Если метод hashCode() вызывается несколько раз на одном и том же
   >   объекте, каждый раз он должен возвращать одно и то же число.
3. > Правило 1 не работает в обратную сторону. Одинаковый хэш-код может
   >   быть у двух разных объектов.

Я запутался помогите разобраться: 
Почему в 3 правило написано мол правило 1 не работает в обратную сторону?

 Получается 1 правило 2 объекта равны и у них хэш-код одинаковый. 
А 3 правило так же одинаковый хэш-код у 2 объектов или я не очень понимаю? Почему в 1 правило написано если 2 объекта равны, а в 3 правило написано одинаковый хэш-код может быть у двух РАЗНЫХ объектов, как понять разных?

Comment: Вся суть в том, что множество объектов ограничено только Вашей фантазией, а множество хэш-кодов ограничено диапазоном типа `Integer`. Исходя из этого, кол-во различных объектов может быть больше, чем кол-во различных хэш-кодов, откуда следует, что у разных объектов может быть одинаковый хэш-код (т.н. коллизия). Сначала проверяется хэш-код, а затем `equals`. Если хэш-коды разные, то и объекты гарантированно разные и проверять на `equals` смысла нет. Если же хэш-коды одинаковые, то необходимо еще проверить на `equals`.

Comment: @post_zeew а если использовать `BigInteger`?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Примечание:** *предполагается, что в классе переопределен метод `hashCode()`.*

По хорошему, у разных объектов хешкод должен быть разный. Но на практике иногда происходит по другому. Очень часто это происходит из-за несовершенства формулы для вычисления хешкода.

Пример: хеш строки считается по длине строки: `length*3`. Тогда у строк `foo` и `bar` одинаковые хеши.

---

Вообще, хешкод используется для того, чтобы можно было точно сказать, что объекты разные.  Но не для того, чтобы сказать, что они одинаковые. Одинаковый хешкод - не гарантия одинаковых объектов.

---

Обычно он используется для сравнения объектов:
Допустим, у вас есть объект, в котором есть много-много полей. В большинстве случаев объекты для сравнения будут неравны. Чтобы не сравнивать кучу переменных(если объекты не равны), можно сначала сравнивать хешкод(т.к., если хеш различается, то объекты точно различны). Если хеши отличаются - можно дальше не сравнивать переменные. Если одинаковы - дальше нужно сравнить переменные(т.к., если хеши одинаковы, то это не значит, что объекты одинаковы).

---

Ну и последнее - почти всегда возвращаемый тип метода `hashCode()` - `int`. У `int` есть определенный предел(от -21... до +21..., если я не ошибаюсь). Если разных объектов будет больше, чем этот предел, то физически нельзя сгенерировать разные хеши для всех объектов. Т.е., при использовании хешей можно увеличить производительность программы.

---

Попробую объяснить правила:

- У одинаковых объектов всегда одинаковые хеши
- У одного и того же объекта всегда должен быть неизменяемый хешкод(если значения внутри объекта не изменились)
- У разных объектов иногда могут быть одинаковые хеши

Comment: А то есть в моём первом правило где я написал в вопросе, там имеют ввиду у одинаковых объектов всегда одинаковые хэши как я понял?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван да

Comment: @AntonSorokin по умолчанию - разные

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ?

Comment: `А то есть в моём первом правило где я написал в вопросе, там имеют ввиду у одинаковых объектов всегда одинаковые хэши как я понял? – Петровченко Иван` `@ПетровченкоИван да – Anton Sorokin`

Comment: по умолчанию, без переопределенного метода `hashcode` одинаковые объекты (разные объекты в куче с одинаковыми полями) вернут разный хэш код...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ аа, вот вы про что. Я имел ввиду с переопределенным методом.

Comment: из вашей переписки я бы не сказал что Иван это имел в виду

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если объекты сравниваются по хешам, то предполагается что у них переопределены методы

Comment: Это не очевидно тем кто только познает java

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну, думаю что он поймет это из комментариев, а в ответ я добавлю информацию

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван на всякий случай прочитайте нашу переписку

Comment: @StrangerintheQ он и так ее увидит, уведомления даже от ответов приходят

Comment: А почему у разные объектов, не может случиться такое, что хеш-коды будут одинаковые?....